# Django - dictionary gets empty on next endpoint

Tags: python, django, multithreading, dictionary

i've a program which starts multiple threads with data from database and i store the thread object in a dictionary.

`thread_manager.py`

```
threads = {}

............

#controller for /start-threads

def start_threads(request):
    datas = Data.objects.all()
    for data in datas:
        thread = MyThread(data)
        threads[data.id] = thread
        thread.start()
    return HttpResponse("all threads are running")

def get_thread(id,request):
        return threads[id]
```

at this point *threads* dictionary has all the threads in it and i can access the thread object with threads[id], now if try to get the thread from another endpoint (im using django)

```
views.py

import thread_manager
def get_thread(request, id):
   thread = thread_manager.get_thread(id, request)
   return HttpResponse("got thread with id {0}".format(id))
```

the threads dictionary is empty at this point(ofc i get a keyerror), if i run this on local server everything works fine. if i run this on live server which has uwsgi running django. it doesnt work, is this a problem with uWsgi or am i doing anything wrong, thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is almost certainly running with more than one process. But threads belong to a single process; you can't access them from a different one.

You don't say what you're doing with these threads, but offline work is almost always better done with a specific system such as Celery.

Comment: you are right, leme tweak the number and check back again, thanx

Comment: btw is there a better way to store threads || to access them ?